# I need 50 reputation points to post a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments

This restriction is really blocking me. I'd like to comment on a working solution, and confirm that it is working.

I'd like to comment here:
[How to bring back Photo Viewer in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/947672/how-to-bring-back-photo-viewer-in-windows-10)

Comment: Yes, you really do need 50 reputation points to comment, and no, it's not hard at all to get that many. 10 upvotes of your questions or 5 upvotes of your answers will get it done. You **can** comment on your own questions and answers, by the way.

Comment: Commenting on my own questions wouldn't solve the question I wanted to help solving. :/

Comment: If you confirmed that the solution is working, great! You only need 15 points to upvote, which is all that's required to say "hey, this post helped me out."

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you might be able to submit your update in the corresponding Chat room.

Answer (score 4):

There really is no trick to getting reputation points.  You just have to participate in the SU community by answering question, editing, etc.  A good start is to follow some tags that you are knowledgeable about.  [This](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) will probably help you out.

Answer (score 3):

Like nhinkle said in a comment (how ironic, in a way) to your question, commenting is not how you indicate here that a particular answer worked for you. Instead, the way to do that is to upvote and (if it is your own question) accept an answer.

See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) in the help center. While the text is written from the perspective of *your own* question being answered, except for the part on accepting an answer, it is equally valid when reading answers to *someone else's* question.